# How to get size of iPad/iPhone app programmatically in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, swift

I'm trying to get the size of my an app programmatically. The app downloads large amounts of audio files, and I'm trying to check that when I delete files, the app size diminishes as expected. So far the only way I know how to do this is by looking in the settings of the iPad, but the numbers there don't seem to be correct always.

```
func getAppSize(){
    let paths : NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    var errorP = NSErrorPointer()
    let pathDictionary: NSDictionary = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfFileSystemForPath(paths.firstObject as String, error: errorP)!
    if(pathDictionary.count != 0){
        var fileSystemSizeInBytes: Double = pathDictionary.objectForKey("NSFileSystemSize") as Double
        var fileSystemSizeInMegaBytes : Double = fileSystemSizeInBytes/1000000
        println("Total Space: \(fileSystemSizeInMegaBytes) MB")
    }else{

    }
}
```

Currently I'm just using the File-System Attirbute Key for the File System Size, which I expected to be the size of my current app, but since it is returning 249 GB, its obviouslly reading my entire MacBook File System size, rather than the simulator's document path.

I looked up the other Attribute Key options and found:

```
let NSFileSystemSize: NSString!
let NSFileSystemFreeSize: NSString!
let NSFileSystemNodes: NSString!
let NSFileSystemFreeNodes: NSString!
let NSFileSystemNumber: NSString!
```

However, I haven't found a key that specifies the size of the actual space taken by my app. I'm thinking maybe there is a way to get all the nodes, and then add up their sizes, but I'm not quite sure how to do that.

**EDIT:** 
So the bundle does appear to give me my apps size, but without any of the mp3 files I save into the document path. I'm guessing I might be saving them to the wrong spot or something, here is a simplified version of how I save them to the app.

```
//Make HTTP Request Ect... before here...
if(data.length > 1000){
    let documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.LibraryDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
    let localUrl = uuid + ".mp3"
    let destPath = (documentPath[0] as String) + "/" + localUrl
    data.writeToFile(destPath, atomically: true)
    var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
    data.writeToFile(destPath, options: NSDataWritingOptions.DataWritingAtomic, error: error)
    if(error != nil){
        println("data write error: \(error.memory?.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2), "the file systems in OS X and iOS handle the persistent storage of data files, apps, and the files associated with the operating system itself." Also [according to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/), "an NSBundle object represents a location in the file system that groups code and resources that can be used in a program," so your app's main bundle is the location where its files live. And according to [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html), each iOS app consists of a bundle, documents directory, library, and tmp.

To get the total size of your app, enumerate through the bundle, documents, library, and tmp subpaths, ex:

```
func appSize() {

    // Go through the app's bundle
    let bundlePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath
    let bundleArray:NSArray = NSFileManager.defaultManager().subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath(bundlePath, error: nil)!
    let bundleEnumerator = bundleArray.objectEnumerator()
    var fileSize: UInt64 = 0

    while let fileName:String = bundleEnumerator.nextObject() as? String {
        let fileDictionary:NSDictionary = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(bundlePath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName), error: nil)!
        fileSize += fileDictionary.fileSize();
    }

    // Go through the app's document directory
    let documentDirectory:NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectoryPath:NSString = documentDirectory[0] as NSString
    let documentDirectoryArray:NSArray = NSFileManager.defaultManager().subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath(documentDirectoryPath, error: nil)!
    let documentDirectoryEnumerator = documentDirectoryArray.objectEnumerator()

    while let file:String = documentDirectoryEnumerator.nextObject() as? String {
        let attributes:NSDictionary = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(documentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file), error: nil)!
        fileSize += attributes.fileSize();
    }

    // Go through the app's library directory
    let libraryDirectory:NSArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.LibraryDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)
    let libraryDirectoryPath:NSString = libraryDirectory[0] as NSString
    let libraryDirectoryArray:NSArray = NSFileManager.defaultManager().subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath(libraryDirectoryPath, error: nil)!
    let libraryDirectoryEnumerator = libraryDirectoryArray.objectEnumerator()

    while let file:String = libraryDirectoryEnumerator.nextObject() as? String {
        let attributes:NSDictionary = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(libraryDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file), error: nil)!
        fileSize += attributes.fileSize();
    }

    // Go through the app's tmp directory
    let tmpDirectoryPath:NSString = NSTemporaryDirectory()
    let tmpDirectoryArray:NSArray = NSFileManager.defaultManager().subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath(tmpDirectoryPath, error: nil)!
    let tmpDirectoryEnumerator = tmpDirectoryArray.objectEnumerator()

    while let file:String = tmpDirectoryEnumerator.nextObject() as? String {
        let attributes:NSDictionary = NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(tmpDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file), error: nil)!
        fileSize += attributes.fileSize();
    }

    var fileSystemSizeInMegaBytes : Double = Double(fileSize)/1000000
    println("Total App Space: \(fileSystemSizeInMegaBytes) MB")
}
```

Comment: So the numbers make a ton more sense now using the bundle, its giving the app size as 12.95 MB, but I know that the actual size is much larger than this (100MB- 500MB) depending on how many of the files have been downloaded. I'm thinking I might be saving my files in the wrong spot. I'll edit my post to show where I'm saving them in code

Comment: @Unome Oh, if files are being downloaded then they won't be found in the app bundle. We'll have to also search those folders to get the full size.

Comment: I added more code showing where I save them, the funny thing is I save them to the document path via the .LibraryDirectory which is what I was searching on in the beginning, so maybe I'm saving them to the wrong spot.

Comment: @Unome Updated to calculate your bundle + your .LibraryDirectory

Comment: That seemed to work pretty good, I'm still getting a discrepancy of 6MB off of what the iPad storage tells me and what this function returns. It gives 145 MB vs 151 MB, and the gap seems to grow linearly with additional file downloads, but overall it should more than suit my needs. Thanks! (curiosity still asks... where are those 6MB?)

Comment: @Unome You know what... Maybe there are other directory files that are pre-set with various app data... I'm going to look into that...

Comment: @Unome Just saw Midhun's answer and he's right -- you should be adding the files to the Document's Directory instead... Not that that accounts for those 6 MBs... Still looking into it...

Comment: I actually did switch it to DocumentsDirectory for the 145 vs 151 mb test, so that isn't it.

Comment: @Unome There's some info at this link about the application directories: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_the_file_system/  Seems as if the app consists of the bundle + documents + library + tmp so we could perhaps also add in library and tmp to get the total size.

Comment: @Unome Updated to account for all of that.

Comment: I think there is still something missing. I am using this method and system tells me that my app used around 350MB but with this method I get 321MB. And when my app groves difference is more and more bigger. Anyone has fix for this? What directory is missing?

Answer (score 3):

Updated and refactored @lyndsey-scott's answer for **Swift 3**. I modified the code to return the size in megabytes as a Float64 instead of printing it to the console, since that was appropriate for my purposes.

```
private class func appSizeInMegaBytes() -> Float64 { // approximate value

    // create list of directories
    var paths = [Bundle.main.bundlePath] // main bundle
    let docDirDomain = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
    let docDirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(docDirDomain, .userDomainMask, true)
    if let docDir = docDirs.first {
        paths.append(docDir) // documents directory
    }
    let libDirDomain = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.libraryDirectory
    let libDirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(libDirDomain, .userDomainMask, true)
    if let libDir = libDirs.first {
        paths.append(libDir) // library directory
    }
    paths.append(NSTemporaryDirectory() as String) // temp directory

    // combine sizes
    var totalSize: Float64 = 0
    for path in paths {
        if let size = bytesIn(directory: path) {
            totalSize += size
        }
    }
    return totalSize / 1000000 // megabytes
}

private class func bytesIn(directory: String) -> Float64? {
    let fm = FileManager.default
    guard let subdirectories = try? fm.subpathsOfDirectory(atPath: directory) as NSArray else {
        return nil
    }
    let enumerator = subdirectories.objectEnumerator()
    var size: UInt64 = 0
    while let fileName = enumerator.nextObject() as? String {
        do {
            let fileDictionary = try fm.attributesOfItem(atPath: directory.appending("/" + fileName)) as NSDictionary
            size += fileDictionary.fileSize()
        } catch let err {
            print("err getting attributes of file \(fileName): \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    return Float64(size)
}
```

Comment: Hey, I keep getting an app size slightly different than "iPhone Storage" in settings. Any way to get the exact same size?

Comment: No that I know of. Please post if you find the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You are calculating the size of Library Folder. Not your application directory folder size.

According to [NSSearchPathDirectory](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSSearchPathDirectory):

> **NSLibraryDirectory**
>
> Various user-visible documentation, support, and configuration files
>   (/Library).
>
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.

You should change your file saving and calculating code:

**Saving:**

```
//Make HTTP Request Ect... before here...
if(data.length > 1000)
{
    let documentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let uuid = NSUUID().UUIDString
    let localUrl = uuid + ".mp3"
    let destPath = (documentPath[0] as String) + "/" + localUrl
    data.writeToFile(destPath, atomically: true)
    var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
    data.writeToFile(destPath, options: NSDataWritingOptions.DataWritingAtomic, error: error)
    if(error != nil){
        println("data write error: \(error.memory?.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

**Calculating:**

```
func getAppSize()
{
    let paths : NSArray   = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    let path : NSString   = paths.firstObject? as NSString
    let files : NSArray   = NSFileManager.defaultManager().subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath(path, error: nil)!
    let dirEnumerator     = files.objectEnumerator()
    var totalSize: UInt64 = 0
    let fileManager       = NSFileManager.defaultManager();
    while let file:String = dirEnumerator.nextObject() as? String
    {
        let attributes:NSDictionary = fileManager.attributesOfItemAtPath(path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file), error: nil)!
        totalSize += attributes.fileSize();
    }

    var fileSystemSizeInMegaBytes : Double = Double(totalSize)/1000000
    println("Total Space: \(fileSystemSizeInMegaBytes) MB")
}
```

Comment: So what folder should I be calculating?

Answer (score 2):

Building on Lyndsay's answer, here's an updated version for Swift 5. It uses `ByteCountFormatter` to create a human-readable representation of the size.

```
private var appSize: String {
    let bcf = ByteCountFormatter()
    bcf.allowedUnits = [.useMB, .useGB]
    bcf.countStyle = .file
    return bcf.string(fromByteCount: appSizeInBytes())
}

func appSizeInBytes() -> Int64 {
    // create list of directories
    var paths = [Bundle.main.bundlePath] // main bundle
    let docDirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    if let docDir = docDirs.first {
        paths.append(docDir) // documents directory
    }
    let libDirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    if let libDir = libDirs.first {
        paths.append(libDir) // library directory
    }
    paths.append(NSTemporaryDirectory() as String) // temp directory

    // combine sizes
    var totalSize: Int64 = 0
    for path in paths {
        totalSize += byteSize(of: path)
    }
    
    return totalSize
}

func byteSize(of directory: String) -> Int64 {
    var size: Int64 = 0
    let fm = FileManager.default
    if let subdirectories = try? fm.subpathsOfDirectory(atPath: directory) {
        subdirectories.forEach { fileName in
            let fileDictionary = try? fm.attributesOfItem(atPath: directory.appending("/" + fileName)) as NSDictionary
            size += Int64(fileDictionary?.fileSize() ?? 0)
        }
    }
    
    return size
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by app size?
 If you are concerned about the amout of data that you are downloading from the net, as per best practice you should download in the `Cache` directory and be ready to its eviction when the system requires. Or you can save them in the `Documents` directory and pay attention to add the "no backup" attribute to your downloaded files or your app will probably be rejected.